# How can I remove the assets of the application when my application is uninstalled in android?

Tags: android

I am working on an application that takes a huge amount of resources. These resources are kept in assets. And these assets will be kept in an SD card. I would like to know if we can delete these assets implicitly when my application is uninstalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save your files under the directory returned by `Context.getExternalFilesDir` (or `Environment.getExternalStorageDir` for API level below 8, and then put your files in `/Android/data/<package_name>/files/` with respect to that directory), then the files will disappear when your app is removed. These files are also private to your app.

From the docs for `getExternalStorageDir`:

> Applications should not directly use this top-level directory, in order to avoid polluting the user's root namespace. Any files that are private to the application should be placed in a directory returned by `Context.getExternalFilesDir`, which the system will take care of deleting if the application is uninstalled.

For shared files, you can use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`. Those won't go away when your app is uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, there are no functionality or functions exists for the uninstallation of application event. So you can't implement it.